# How can I convert an integer like 3212007 to date 3-21-2007 uisng IBM DB2 SQL?

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion, db2, integer

The dataset I inherited has a DATE column but the values in this column are integers of the form `3212007` which should be `03-21-2007`. I can't get it back into date format.

I can convert the integer to a string using `CAST(myinteger as varchar(8))` without difficulty. Then I can `CAST` that as date by `CAST(CAST(myinteger as varchar(8))` as date) which gets me a date. The problem is that my integer is formatted as `'mmddyyyy'` so for `3212007`, I get `3212-01-07`.

```
select TRANSACTION_DATE from MA_NORFOLK fetch first row only;
[returns: 3212007]

select CAST(TRANSACTION_DATE as VARCHAR) from MA_NORFOLK fetch first row only;
[returns: 3212007]

select CAST(CAST(TRANSACTION_DATE as varchar(8)) as date) from MA_NORFOLK fetch first row only;
[returns: 3212-01-07]
```

Other posts suggest using `CONVERT` command, but all I get are errors

> "DATE" is not valid in the context where it is used..."

Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
date(to_date(digits(dec(3212007, 8)), 'MMDDYYYY'))
```

If you may have one digit for month, there is an alternative:

```
select 
date 
( 
  case when substr(char_dt, 1, 2)='00' 
    then translate('EFGH-0D-0C', char_dt, 'ABCDEFGH')
    else translate('EFGH-AB-CD', char_dt, 'ABCDEFGH')
  end
) dt, char_dt
from 
(
  select digits(dec(i, 8)) char_dt
  from table(values 3212007, 312007) t(i)
) t;

DT         CHAR_DT
---------- --------
2007-03-21 03212007
2007-01-03 00312007
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm. My next order of business is to find out who screwed up the dates in the first place!

Comment: It's good to hear this. Mark the answer as accepted then, please.

Answer (score 0):

This works (at least in MS SQL Server):

```
   SELECT CAST(CONCAT( RIGHT(3212007,4),'-',
       (3212007 / 1000000), '-', ((3212007 % 1000000) / 10000)) AS date)
```

The trick is that you don't know if you will have a single digit, or two-digit month, so you have to start with getting just the right 4 characters as the year. Then by using combinations of modulo and integer divide, you can parse out the month and day.

Of course, you will want to substitute your actual date column for the sample data that I used above.

Comment: IBM's db2 should also support `CONCAT()` and `RIGHT()` functions so this query should also work...

Comment: DB2 doesn't want to accept CONCAT, I get the error "No authorized routine named "CONCAT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.." Mark Barinstein's answer above did the trick. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may works well:

```
create table #temp(
date int
)

insert into #temp (date)
values(3212007),
      (12032019) 

select 
case when len(cast(date as varchar)) = 7 
then 
'0' + left(cast(date as varchar), 1) + '-' + substring(cast(date as varchar), 2,2) + '-' + right(cast(date as varchar), 4)
else  left(cast(date as varchar), 2) + '-' + substring(cast(date as varchar), 3,2) + '-' + right(cast(date as varchar), 4) end
from #temp
```